# ASP.NET code runs using apppool account but how to change this to logged in user account?

Tags: asp.net, .net, security

We know that the code of the ASP.NET application runs under the apppool account.

So, suppose there is a file which needs to be written by code, then we need to give write permission to the Apppool account on that file.

Now, every user logged into the site will have permission to write the file. Say we have scenario in which there is a file on server, and has been given the write permission only to USER A, then how to allow only User A to be able to write to file.?

Comment: Look up "ASP.NET Impersonation" - lots and lots of resources out there to explain this :)

Comment: You have role attached to the users and the code checks to see if that user has that role. Naff all to do with the apppool account. After that it depends if the role is internal to your app, or pulled in from windows.

Comment: Can you write an answer please